# Presto SQL - Looking to explode Table of IDs to include predefined row numbers

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena, trino

Apologies if this title was a bit confusing. It's tough to articulate this problem in a sentence.

Here is my current table

```
ID
A
B
C
```

I'd like to explode this table to look like this:

```
ID temp
A. 1
A. 2
A. 3  
B. 1
B. 2
B. 3
C. 1
C. 2
C  3
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `cross join`:

```
select c.*, v.temp
from current c cross join
     (values (1), (2), (3)) v(temp);
```